# How can I replace a javascript for loop with a forEach and get access to the index for each iteration?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript:

```
factory.remove = function (arr, property, num) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (arr[i][property] === num)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
};
```

Can someone tell me how I could change the for loop to use a .forEach instead? What I am not sure about is how in the forEach I can access the `i` ?  Also if I use the forEach will I be able to do a splice of that array or is it not possible?

Comment: What do you believe is the advantage of `foreach` over `for` here?

Comment: If you have to: yes, it's second argument in the forEach callback.

Comment: added an answer which might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (arr[i][property] === num)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
```

could be written like this

```
arr.forEach(function(elem,index){
    if(elem[property]===num)
       arr.splice(index, 1);
})
```